# Return redirect to new window in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Basically, what I'm trying to do is open up a new window to the user for previewing some form data they have submitted.

I'm trying to do it from my controller using the code:

`Return JavaScript("window.open('http://www.google.com')")`

But all it does is return a file download dialog instead of opening a new window.

Have I missed something or am I doing it wrong entirely?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to forum my own resolution from many hours of trial and error, by ultimately changing my form post to a $.ajax post which has allowed me to execute window.open to the relevant url on success.

Answer (score 1):

You can Redirect from your controller action using :

```
Redirect(YourUrl)
```

or if you want to have a popup, you should include your javascript in your view and trigger it from there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('http://www.google.com');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to add a Css class attribute to your ActionLink and have a script in jQuery that process all links with this Css class so they will open in a new window. You can't do this on the controller's side, it has to be front end.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(item.Title, MVC.Controller.Action(param1, param2, ..,), new { @class="style1" })%>
```

and in jQuery

```
$('a .style1').click(function () {
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

If your not using an ActionLink or have more question provide us with more details so we can help ;)

Comment: That's not quite what I'm trying to achieve. It's in the controller as it's a result of a controller action.

Comment: But your action is called by something in your view? A form, a link, a button? Can you provide the view or more information/code?

Comment: In short what the view has is a form with a series of buttons. One of these buttons is a preview button that submits previewed data to a table, which then should lead to what I'm trying to achieve at the moment with opening a new window with said preview.